# Tokenizing string in (old) Lua

Tags: lua, tokenize, lua-patterns, wireshark-dissector

I am trying to tokenize NMEA sentence using Lua. The current Lua version (available at https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) works as expected:

```
local index = 0
for token in string.gmatch("$HEHDT,99.00,,T*2F", "[%w.]*") do
 print(string.format("%d: %s", index, token))
 index = index + 1
end
```

giving:

```
0: 
1: HEHDT
2: 99.00
3: 
4: T
5: 2F
Your program ran successfully.
```

However, using Lua 5.1.4 (and 5.2.4 in Wireshark)

```
0:
1: HEHDT
2:
3: 99.00
4:
5:
6: T
7:
8: 2F
9:
```

Is there a way to achieve the same tokenization output using an older Lua as using the current version?

Comment: That seems impossible without a real full-fledged regex support.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is definitely possible without full-fledged regex in the current Lua version - as seen in the first example. I'm looking for a way to do it in the previous version as well.

Comment: That is what I mean: in the 5.4.2 it seems impossible, the engine behavior with empty matches has changed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Lua patterns are powerful enough, so that in most cases (IMO 95%) you don't need full-fledged regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local index = 0
local str = "$HEHDT,99.00,,T*2F"
for token in string.gmatch(str.."$", "([%w.]*)[^%w.]") do
   print(string.format("%d: %s", index, token))
   index = index + 1
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't that perform poorly for very long strings though? (Because of the concatenation, that is)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - It's hard to say for sure.  Please make a benchmark and share the results.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct as it does the job. The max length of NMEA sentence is 82, so I'm fine with performance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Lua is detecting the empty string between two tokens as a separate token for whatever reason. This is unintuitive, but not completely wrong, as `[%w]*` matches the empty string. You can work around this issue by using `string.find` and incrementing the position by two instead of one after every match:

```lua
local index = 0
local str = "$HEHDT,99.00,,T*2F"

local a, b = 0, 1
while true do
  a, b = str:find("[%w.]*", b+2)
  if not a then break end
  print(string.format("%d: [%i,%i] %s", index, a, b, str:sub(a, b)))
  index = index + 1
end
```

That code could probably be rewritten to be a bit prettier, but I'll leave that to you :D